# Complex Linq Collection Query

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have this DB diagram and want to make a query to find all UserLists in a given region. RegionId is supplied.

[image: DB Diagram]

So I can get all the departments by this code (may not be the best way..):

```
var region = context.Regions.Find(regionId);
IEnumerable<Department> departments = region.Areas
            .SelectMany(a => a.Workplaces)
            .SelectMany(w => w.Departments);
```

The **Account** can have many **UserLists**, and an **Account** can be linked to many **Departments**. Can someone formulate a queryto achieve this please?

Comment: I have just realised this model is messed up. Departments >-< Accounts should be many to many... This DB diagram is useless :-(

Comment: Diagram is now correct... grr @ downvoters :( will be trying the answer below later today and will get back soon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the let syntax (or the .Select method) to navigate the ManyToOne relationship.

```
var query =
  from r in context.Regions
  where r.RegionId == regionId
  from a in r.Areas
  from w in a.Workplaces
  from d in w.Departments
  from da in d.DepartmentAccounts
  let acc = da.Account
  from u in acc.UserLists
  select u;


var query2 = context.Regions.Where(r => r.RegionId == regionId)
  .SelectMany(r => r.Areas)
  .SelectMany(a => a.Workplaces)
  .SelectMany(w => w.Departments)
  .SelectMany(d => d.DepartmentAccounts)
  .Select(da => da.Account)
  .SelectMany(acc => acc.UserLists);
```

Comment: OP is judge: "I have this DB diagram and want to make a query to find all UserLists in a given region"

Comment: I do want all the lists where the list Account's related departments, belong  in the given region.

Comment: @Saeed OP: "Can someone formulate a queryto achieve this please?" [tag:entity-framework]

Comment: Thanks for the complete example - i would upvote, but reputation is less than 15.

Comment: And as I can see you changed your opinion to output userslist not all data, how you can say my comments are not useful? really I think you downvote me without reason, but rep is not important for me so I'm not care about your manner.

Answer (score 0):

for completeness the final code was:

```
        List<UserList> query2 = context.Regions.Where(r => r.RegionId == regionId)
            .SelectMany(r => r.Areas)
            .SelectMany(a => a.Workplaces)
            .SelectMany(w => w.Departments)
            .SelectMany(d => d.AccountsAllowedToPost)
            .Distinct()
            .SelectMany(da => da.Lists).ToList();
```